# Searching DB Text field for multiple values VB6, ADO, SQL

Tags: sql, vb6

I have a database setup with a text field that has a bunch of stuff in it.
It might look something like this:

```
'#TR#$$C30041A|2|520$$C30041B|2|Comment#TR#$$C30042A|2|530$$C30042B|2|Comment 2'
```

I have a few thousand of these records in my database.
I need to search for any records that have a certain number INSIDE that string, but it can be one of a hundred or more different numbers. If I JUST want to search for a single number (in this case, 520), my query string would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `DB` WHERE `Data` LIKE '%$$C[0-9]%A|[1-4]|520$$%'
```

And I can get the records I want that have #520.
But, If I want to get a hundred different numbers, I don't know how to search for this.
I thought something like in RegEx would work:

```
SELECT * FROM `DB` WHERE `Data` LIKE '%$$C[0-9]%A|[1-4]|(520|530|540|600|601|602)$$%'
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Do you want to find all the rows that match any one of the numbers in your list? If so, you could construct a dynamic select with a lot of `OR`s in the `WHERE` (one for each item in the list) but that won't be pretty.

Comment: Yeah, I just need to find rows with any of the numbers in them. I thought about doing a giant list of 'OR's, but if I have to find 100+ numbers I don't know if that will work... 
For fields that just are one, single code, I use a lot of
`WHERE field IN ('100', '101', '200', '202')` logic, but that won't work here, either...

Comment: Depending on your database and access library, you could use a table valued parameter. Or load the numbers into a temporary table and join on it in your select.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what any of that means lol
I'm using VB6 with ADODB and an Access Database.

Comment: Ha, I don't think Access supports either of those (but I could be wrong). I think your best bet is to concatenate the `OR`s or loop through your list and run the select for each one and append the results into a list as you go along.

Comment: I imagine it would not be (easily) possible to do something like:
Find all records with a number inside of a text field where that number is < something?

Comment: How big is your table? Are you willing to bring back all the rows with a number in that bit and then filter out (in VB code) the rows where the number is greater than or equal to something

Comment: `inner join a_working_table w on '%' + w.matchMe + '%' like db.data`